# What is the order of matching for similar patterns with different labels in spaCy's EntityRuler?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to add an EntityRuler pipeline into an existing statistical NER model to better handle more structured entity types like numbers, age and money.

However, some of these numerical patterns may be quite similar or have significant overlap with one another, especially if we have a mix of general and more specific patterns. An example of a problem that I am facing is as follows:

```
    {"label": "NUMBER", "pattern": [{"LIKE_NUM": true}]}
    {"label": "AGE", "pattern": {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^(1[0-4]|[1-9])?[0-9]$"}}]}
```

I have one rather general pattern that simply uses the `LIKE_NUM` token attribute to label a generic `NUMBER` entity; and another more specific pattern using regex to match numbers from 0 to 149 to be of entity type `AGE`. When I pass in the sentence `I am 20`, I want the EntityRuler to check against the more specific pattern first before moving on to more general patterns, such that it returns `AGE` as the label in this case, rather than labelling it as a generic `NUMBER`.

I tried rearranging the order of the patterns in my `patterns.jsonl` file to test if the order of adding the patterns into the pipeline somehow affects the priority assigned to the pattern. However, both cases returned the more generic `NUMBER` label.

Just to see what would happen, I fed in the sentence `I am 20 1 2 01 123 1410 999 001 10 51 001 010 149 150 151` and got this result consistently -
`Ents: [('20', 'NUMBER'), ('1', 'AGE'), ('2', 'NUMBER'), ('01', 'NUMBER'), ('123', 'NUMBER'), ('1410', 'NUMBER'), ('999', 'NUMBER'), ('001', 'NUMBER'), ('10', 'AGE'), ('51', 'AGE'), ('001', 'NUMBER'), ('010', 'NUMBER'), ('149', 'NUMBER'), ('150', 'NUMBER'), ('151.', 'NUMBER')]`, which seemed to arbitrarily assign `AGE` or `NUMBER` to values from 0 to 149.

This raises 2 questions that I hope someone could help to answer:

1. How / in what order exactly does the EntityRuler go through each of the added patterns?
2. Would it be better practice in such NER tasks to avoid having such general umbrella patterns/labels altogether? Or is the issue more of overlapping/similar patterns?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?